# Como camuflar um link de pagina

Tags: php, paginação, link

exemplo vejo muitas paginas criando um arquivo m3u e hospedando mas se tentar colar endereço no navegador para fazer o download do arquivo a pagina redireciona sem baixar ou mostrar o arquivo para outra pagina.  isto é feito em paginas php

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 3):

O que acontece é que a chamada verifica o [REFERER](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer), conforme o wikipedia:

> O referer, ou HTTP referer (é escrito erroneamente como referer nas especificacoes HTTP oficiais e padronizado assim desde então1 ), é um campo de cabeçalho HTTP que identifica o endereço da página web (i.e. o URI ou IRI) que liga ao recurso sendo solicitado. Pela verificação do referer, a nova página web pode ver de onde a requisição se originou. (Em suma: saber de onde o usuário veio, ou seja, qual página que ele estava que o mandou para seu site).
>
> Na situação mais comum, isto significa que quando um usuário clica em um hiperlink em um navegador web, o navegador envia uma solicitação ao servidor que armazena a página web de destino. A solicitação inclui o campo referer, que indica a última página que o usuário estava (aquela que ele clicou no link).
>
> O log do referer é usado para permitir que sites web e servidores web identifiquem de onde as pessoas o estão visitando, para propósitos promocionais ou estatísticos.
>
> Isto significa que quando um usuário clica em uma ligação, a partir de um navegador web, o navegador envia uma solicitação para o servidor que contém a página de destino. O pedido inclui a informação do referrer, informando a página que o usuário estava anteriormente.

### Entendendo o que é o REFERER (http)

Para detalhar, suponha que você tem uma página/site chamado `http://exemplo.com/pagina.html` e nesta página há um player:

```
<object classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95"
codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
type="application/x-oleobject">
    <param name="fileName" value="musicas.m3u">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
     pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"
     src="musicas.m3u">
</object>
```

Quando o player chamar o arquivo `musicas.m3u`, está requisição irá receber algo como:

```
GET /musicas.m3u HTTP/1.1
Host: exemplo.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Referer: exemplo.com/pagina.html
```

Veja o `Referer: exemplo.com/pagina.html` detecta que a chamada veio de `exemplo.com/pagina.html`.

Porém se você copiar o endereço do playlist e tentam abrir diretamente `http://exemplo.com/musicas.m3u`, o navegador vai enviar a requisição desta maneira:

```
GET /musicas.m3u HTTP/1.1
Host: exemplo.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Veja que agora não temos o REFERER.

### Como usar o REFERER

Você pode usar PHP, mas se os seus arquivos são estáticos (não são gerados por páginas .php, são arquivos reais chamados `.m3u`) você pode usar o `.htaccess` para impedir o acesso acaso não tenha o [REFERER](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) (ou seja chamada direta), isto também irá impedir que outros sites usem o seu .m3u em páginas externas, poupando o trafego do seu site, está técnica é chamada `prevent hotlink` ou `stop hotlink`.

Crie um arquivo na usa pasta raiz (se estiver usando o Apache) e adicione isto (também é necessário prevenir o cache):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?exemplo.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.m3u$ - [NC,F,L] #NC é para case-insensitive 

<FilesMatch "\.(?i:m3u)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Se você chamar qualquer arquivo `.m3u` pelo url do browser ou por outro site ele irá bloquear o acesso, mostrando o erro `403`, se aberto pelo player ele irá abrir o arquivo normalmente.

Porém se o seu arquivo `.m3u`, na verdade é um arquivo `.php`, crie um arquivo chamado `playlist.php` e adicione isto:

```
<?php
$g = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s');
header('Expires: ' . $g . ' GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . $g . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');

$parsed = empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? false : parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

if (false === empty($parsed['host']) && $parsed['host'] !== 'exemplo.com') {
    header('Content-Type: audio/x-mpegurl'); //Aplica o mimetype necessário para o player reconhecer o arquivo que é gerado dinamicamente
    echo file_get_contents('arquivo.m3u');//Lê o seu arquivo
} else {
    echo 'Hot link';
}
```

E deve chama-lo assim:

```
<object classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95"
codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
type="application/x-oleobject">
    <param name="fileName" value="playlist.php">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
     pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"
     src="playlist.php">
</object>
```

Se chamado pelo player o arquivo `.php` gera o playlist usado o `file_get_contents`, já se for chamado pelo url do browser ou outro site ele irá mostrar o seguinte erro `Hot link`.

### Controvérsias

Apesar desta técnica ajudar a proteger, tudo pode ser burlado e realmente isto é só uma prevenção, mas não é 100% seguro, um jeito simples de burlar é injetar o link do `.m3u` na página do site usando javascript (pelo console do browser) e se clicar no link é provável que consiga fazer o download.

Comment: mais ou menos isso mas que eu preciso seria ter arquivo m3u hospedado  em algum lugar e no meu site ter uma pagina que gerasse este link mas só para kodi por exemplo se fosse colocado o link no navegador redirecionasse para outra pagina sem baixar o m3u

Comment: @JosneiMachado basta trocar `echo 'Hot link';` por `header('Location: http://outrosite');` ou se for o .htaccess basta usar a flag `[R=302]`, entendeu?

Comment: fiz por htacess  RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://site.com.br/nv/user.php.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://site.com.br/nv/user.php$      [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.site.com.br/nv/user.php.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.site.com.br/nv/user.php$      [OR]
RewriteRule .*\.(.*)$ http://outrosite.com.br [R=302]

Comment: mas o play em vez da lista m3u carrega o html do outro site

Comment: Você adicionou várias coisas que eu não adicionei no `.htaccess`, ou seja não tem haver com o código que citei. Tente entender o que passei na resposta, além do código porfavor @JosneiMachado

Answer (score 2):

Se estiver usando servidor `Apache`, pode restringir o acesso ao arquivo para um DOMÍNIO ou IP criando um arquivo `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?seudominio [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?seudominio.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(m3u|mp3)$ - [F]
```